# Two definitions of analyticity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm confused between two definitions of analytic complex functions.

- [1] A complex function is said to be analytic on a region R if it is complex differentiable at every point in R.
- [2] An analytic function is a function that is locally given by a convergent power series.

Could someone clarify how to go from [1] to [2]?
** This question came up when I was thinking about why a polynomial $p(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ is analytic.

### Reference

- [1] https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticFunction.html
- [2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Analyticity_and_differentiability

Comment: It comes from the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: hmm, sorry, could you expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: I can see that for a $z \in R \subset \mathbb{C}$, by Cauchy integral formula, $f(z)$ has a form of indefinite integral, which is a power series. But it doesn't tell me why this series has to be convergent to hold the analyticity..

Comment: It is  a standard theorem proved in any book on Complex Analysis. You could study the proof in Rudin's RCA and tell us if you get stuck.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I found the publicly available PDF, could you tell me which theorem?
https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf

Comment: Theorems 10.6 and 10.16

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unencumbered by history, the authors of todays calculus textbooks are used to confuse  some different concepts, that became logically equivalent around 1900.

0. A locally smooth real function $x\to f(x)$ has a Taylor expansion and at best, the infinite series converges to the function in some region. These type of infinetly often differntiable real functions with a series representation are called real analytic functions, because the series coefficients can be determined by  analysis aka real calculus. A complex analytic function is the same concept with $x\to z = x+ i y$. By this definition, the analytic function have a series representation in $(z-z_0)^n$ and do not depend on $z^\star=x-iy$ and all formulas can be taken for granted as if the complex $z$ is a real $x$, e.g. $f'(z) = f'(x) /; x\to x+ i y$
1. This brings up the simple definition of Cauchy and Riemann, but difficult to prove: Any complex differentiable complex function is analytic in some open circle around the point of differentiability.
2. From vector analysis in 2 dimensions, the countour integral of a vector field does not depend on the countour, but only on the two points coneccted, iff $\text{rot} \ v=0 $ in an open, simply connected neighbood of both points. The picture of the Gaussian plane $z = x+ i y \to (x,y)$ reveals, that complex differentiability is equivalent to $\text{rot} (\Re f,\Im f) =0$.
3. It follows  the famous integral theorem of Cauchy: Closed contour integrals of complex differentiable as well as analytic functions in a simply connected open domain vanish. Integrals are countour independent and analytic functions aka complex differentiable functions are holomorphic, that is, they are infinitely often differentiable and integrable and their series expansions converge absolutely in the same open disc and the differentiated and integrated series converge absolutely in the same disk to the differntials and integrals.

Answer (score 0):

This is found in every complex analysis book: look in some of them.

The argument you seek is a basic and fantastic illustration of the utility of the Cauchy integral formula, which has no analogue in real analysis, and the equivalence of those two properties you listed is not true for real-valued functions on a real interval: real-differentiability does not imply local representation by a power series.